# Transfer iptables rules to another server (almost) real time

Tags: iptables

I'm running 2 cPanel servers with `ConfigServer Security & Firewall` plugin. One of the functions of the plugin is to block via iptables (temporarily and/or permanently) IPs which fail various authentications (POP3/IMAP, SMTP, FTP, webmail, mod_security and such).

Now, i'd like to push those IP blocks to the border router to drop packets as soon as possible (and doing so protecting the other machines on the network).

Keep in mind that after N failed logins IP is blocked for 5 minutes, then re-allowed. If multiple bans occours in an hour IP is blocked permanently and should be unlocked "by hand". So I need a *near realtime* solution.

What I'm looking for is a better way than firing some **cronjobs** both on cPanels and border router to:

- dump the rules to file
- transfer the file to border router (via scp/sftp)
- load the rules from the file in the border router

I'm aware that I will need some scripts to parse and modify the rules as cPanels have **one** ethernet interface and some aliases while border router has **two** ehternet interfaces and some loopbacks.

All machines involved use Linux.

**EDIT** as per @pjmorse comment.

The plugin consists of a bunch of perl and config files. The part I'm intrested in is a process which scans logfiles (`lfd`) and installs `iptables` rules (and sends an alert email). Fact is, it upgrades quite often (one or two times a week) and itself is >7000 lines of perl so I'm not comfortable on tampering with it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this plugin, but I can mentally sketch out a solution for this, and I bet other users could too. One important piece of information: can the plugin be hacked or hooked to run an external script when it adds an IP to iptables?

Comment: @pjmorse i don't know but i can check it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution that would provide a realtime 'transfer' would be to replace `iptables` with a script that calls `iptables` on the router.

1. generate an ssh key pair, and authorize the key to log into root on the gateway host
2. create `/path/to/override/iptables` as a script which runs
   `ssh root@routerhost iptables "$@"`
3. In the startup script which starts your web server, set `PATH="/path/to/override:$PATH"`

Now whenever the plugin goes looking for `iptables` it'll find the one in `/path/to/override` since it was specified first in `$PATH`. It'll run the script when passes all the arguments the script received to `iptables` on `routerhost`.
However if the plugin uses an absolute path to `iptables`, you will instead have to manually change the path in the plugin.

Comment: Actually, this is a really nice solution. No need to change the PATH enviroment as I can configure the `iptables` path on the plugin so I can point it to my script! Didn't think of it! Actually the script will be slightly more complex because interfaces differs and also on the border router I need to put the rules on the FORWARD chain and not the INPUT chain, but nothing too complicated ;)